# Prevent button in Reactjs from automatically submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the button to not automatically submit so that it waits for the user to select an item on the page to save to the db.

Here is the function I am trying to call:

```
saveAndModal = (id, title, cover, ISBN, event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(ISBN);
        this.save(id);
        this.modal(title, cover);
    };
```

Here is where I am calling it:

```
<SaveBtn
        key={book.id}
        saveAndModal={this.saveAndModal(
                book.id,
                book.volumeInfo.title,
                book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
                book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier)} />
```

I have found multiple resources showing the use of event.preventDefault() in react.  When I attempt to use it on a function that requires more than one parameter, I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined.

Comment: Although the two answers are correct, I think I can offer an improved code structure if you will provide the `SaveBtn` component in your question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an event propogation/bubbling issue. It's because an event listener is expecting a function, and you are immediately invoking the function inside. The solution is to return a function that still uses those arguments, which requires a double `return` statement.

```
// note the extra arrow function return
saveAndModal = (id, title, cover, ISBN) => (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(ISBN);
        this.save(id);
        this.modal(title, cover);
    };
```

Comment: You should  remove the `event` in the outer function args.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the event, you can pass your function through an anonymous function in your element, like this:

```
 <SaveBtn
    key={book.id}
    saveAndModal={(event) => this.saveAndModal(
            book.id,
            book.volumeInfo.title,
            book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
            book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
            event
)} />
```

By doing that, you should be able to use event in your saveAndModal function and preventDefault().

I tried to replicate something similar here: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-gauss-3y5ub